# Reference Request for Orbits of Group Representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-actions, characters

Recently I have been considering a problem that has had me venture into some mathematical territory that is new to me, specifically group representations, words, and character theory. I would appreciate advice into what specific areas/theorems I should learn that apply to this particular question.

**Here is the problem**: I have a group $G$ acting on a very big vector space $V$, which is over $\mathbb{F}_2$. I want to compute the number of orbits of the action of $G$ on $V$. I could use Cauchy-Frobenius and sum the fixed points, but $V$ is too big for that to be feasible. My hope is to be able to use the basis of $V$, which is small, instead. *If* I could factor the image of each basis vector $e_i$ under the action by $g \in G$ into a basis representation
$$e_i^g = f_1e_1 + f_2e_2 + \cdots + f_ne_n$$
then I could calculate the matrix form for each $g$ and use that to find the fixed points. But this task is not easy—I can compute the image of a vector under a transformation by $g$, but I do not know of any way to write this new vector as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

I figure there might be a very general way of understanding the orbits of group representations—that is, of elements of the vector space that are "distinct $\mod G$"—but I do not know enough about character theory, homology, etc. to see the direction to go. If anyone could recommend to me some specific readings that are relevant to problems like this, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Edit: I will also note that I am able to determine the orbits of the action of $G$ on each basis vector (just not in terms of the other basis vectors), so much hope is to exploit this.

Comment: The order of $G$ is even?

Comment: Not necessarily, although if you have a result for when $G$ is even then I would like to hear it.

Comment: I prefer odd orders if the representation is over a field of characteristic $2$. The structure of a representation depends very much on whether the order of the group is odd or even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your request, here are some wonderful sources on representation theory; [Standford group actions](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind1_5.html), [Bowdoin powerpoint on representation theory and orbital varieties](https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/%7Etpietrah/PAPERS/tufts.pdf), hope this helps!